# Error occured while inserting

Tags: ios

I developed iOS app that inserts data in sqlite I created database named studentdb.sqlite and table named std_reg. the std_reg had 5 columns after time I changed and add another table  named  std_payment.but the added table is not working and It displays the fallowing errors:

> DataBaseDemo[1764:892812] DB Error: 1 "no such table: std_payment"
>   2018-04-07 11:16:30.743886+0300 DataBaseDemo[1764:892812] DB Query:
>   INSERT INTO std_payment VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) DataBaseDemo[1764:892812]
>   Error occured while inserting

```
#import "ModelManager.h"


@implementation ModelManager

static ModelManager *instance=nil;

@synthesize database=_database;

+(ModelManager *) getInstance
{

    if(!instance)
    {
        instance=[[ModelManager alloc]init];
        instance.database=[FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Util getFilePath:@"studentdb.sqlite"]];
    }
    return instance;
}

-(void)insertData:(Model *)data
{
    [instance.database open];
 BOOL isInserted=[instance.database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO  std_payment VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",data.ID,data.Rate,data.Package,data.Type,data.Status];
[instance.database close];

    if(isInserted)
        NSLog(@"Inserted Successfully");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error occured while inserting");
}
@end
```

Comment: "no such table: std_payment" - check your database schema.

Comment: how to check  my  database schema I am using fired fox

Comment: use https://sqliteonline.com/ to import your database and see it's schema or if your db is like top secret and you don't want to expose it online then use an app http://sqlitebrowser.org/ or google for one, man! But basically, your schema does not have a `std_payment` table so either update your schema or your code appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The `studentdb.sqlite` file in your bundle has a schema that does not have a table named `std_payment`.

**Either update your schema or your code appropriately.**

---

To check your database schema, you can import the database file using:

- An online viewer to import your database *(but only if you are comfortable exposing it online to an unknown third-party service like the following)*:

  - [SqliteOnline](https://sqliteonline.com/)
  - [SQLite Viewer with Google Drive](http://sqliteviewer.flowsoft7.com/)
- A desktop app

  - [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)
- Some browser extension in the browser of your choice

  - Firefox addon: [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/seamonkey/addon/sqlite-manager/)
  - Chrome extension: [SQLite Viewer with Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sqlite-viewer-with-google/aaeojgplhedihcdhfcgodiepddeecepl)

Comment: How to update my schema using by  SQLite Viewer with Google Drive please give me steps do I fallow. how does updating of  schema  help me

Comment: @MohamedAli That one is for viewing only. Use another option that can open + modify/create a new database. For using the firefox addon try this [link on how-to](https://deparkes.co.uk/2016/03/04/use-firefox-sqlite-manager/)